# Removal of HDD causes kernel panic

Tags: linux, centos, lvm, kernel-panic, grub-legacy

I recently added a 2nd HDD to a system and then proceeded to do a clean install on to this 2nd HDD of CentOS 6.5. The original system was CentOS 5.9. My plan was to leave the original HDD in place so that I could pull data off of it as needed as we migrated several KVMs from **HDD #1** to **HDD #2**.

All this went uneventfully, and I didn't even bother to remove **HDD #1**, figuring we'd "get around to it".

So fast forward to today and I actually attempted to remove **HDD #1** and lo and behold I can't. Booting CentOS 6.5 off of **HDD #2** seems to "know" about the original HDD and kernel panics when **HDD #1** is removed.

[image: ss #1]

[image: ss #2]

The setup of this box is vanilla CentOS 6.5 with the "Virtualization*" YUM groups installed. There is no reference to **HDD #1** in **HDD #2**'s `/etc/fstab`. The only area where I would consider digging deeper is with LVM, since CentOS installs (all Red Hat distros for that matter) make use of LVM when setting up their HDDs.

Here's the stanza from `/etc/grub.conf` in case that might be helpful:

```
title CentOS (2.6.32-431.17.1.el6.x86_64)
    root (hd0,0)
    kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.32-431.17.1.el6.x86_64 ro root=/dev/mapper/vg_catbus-lv_root rd_NO_LUKS rd_LVM_LV=vg_catbus/lv_root LANG=en_US.UTF-8 rd_LV
M_LV=vg_catbus/lv_swap rd_NO_MD quiet SYSFONT=latarcyrheb-sun16 rhgb crashkernel=auto rd_LVM_LV=VolGroup00/LogVol01  KEYBOARDTYPE=pc KEYTABLE=us rd_NO
_DM
    initrd /initramfs-2.6.32-431.17.1.el6.x86_64.img
```

Here too is the LVM setup:

```
$ sudo vgs
  VG         #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize   VFree
  VolGroup00   1   3   0 wz--n- 465.66g    0 
  vg_catbus    1   3   0 wz--n-   1.82t    0 

$ sudo lvs
  LV       VG         Attr       LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  LogVol00 VolGroup00 -wi-a----- 442.19g                                             
  LogVol01 VolGroup00 -wi-ao----  13.69g                                             
  LogVol02 VolGroup00 -wi-a-----   9.78g                                             
  lv_home  vg_catbus  -wi-ao----   1.76t                                             
  lv_root  vg_catbus  -wi-ao----  50.00g                                             
  lv_swap  vg_catbus  -wi-ao----  13.77g           

$ sudo pvs
  PV         VG         Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree
  /dev/sda2  vg_catbus  lvm2 a--    1.82t    0 
  /dev/sdb2  VolGroup00 lvm2 a--  465.66g    0
```

#### Key points

- System crashes when I shutdown down the system, physically disconnect **HDD #1**, and then power the system back up.
- The 500GB HDD is what I'm calling **HDD #1**, the 2TB HDD is what I'm calling **HDD #2**.
- With **HDD #1** connected, I can boot the system just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key item to notice in the output of `/etc/grub.conf` are these types of arguments being passed to the kernel:

```
rd_LVM_LV=VolGroup00/LogVol01
```

Removing this argument from GRUB's `linux ..` line resolved the issue. These are remnants of HDD #1's LVM. These were added automatically by the install to assist you, but in this case, it's caused this pseudo dependency on HDD #1 even when there isn't actually a "real" one.

Simply removing this line from `/etc/grub.conf` resolves it.

```
 title CentOS (2.6.32-431.17.1.el6.x86_64)
    root (hd0,0)
    kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.32-431.17.1.el6.x86_64 ro root=/dev/mapper/vg_catbus-lv_root rd_NO_LUKS rd_LVM_LV=vg_catbus/lv_root LANG=en_US.UTF-8 rd_LV
M_LV=vg_catbus/lv_swap rd_NO_MD quiet SYSFONT=latarcyrheb-sun16 rhgb crashkernel=auto KEYBOARDTYPE=pc KEYTABLE=us rd_NO
_DM
    initrd /initramfs-2.6.32-431.17.1.el6.x86_64.img
```

Take care when making these edits and also be sure to remove them from any of the other `title` entries you may have in your `/etc/grub.conf` too.